# drywall gap again after foundation repair

Tags: repair, drywall, foundation, gap

My foundation (crawl space) was repaired recently, huge job, home not level. There had been a gap in a corner where the sheetrock had dropped down but that side (plus adjoining 90 degree) was reframed & much bracing added everywhere. That gap was closed where the 2 sides meet, but  3 months later it is there again, slight. I KNOW the foundation is solid now (home is on a hill but ostensibly solid), so why would this gap reappear? It's not larger than 1/4 inch. Is this normal settling? Would a patch job take care of it? I don't think my home is moving but I'm concerned. Contractor has since moved so I can't call him. It was a highly professional job but ... ? thank you. (I live in an HOA and I don't know if the ground is shifting? in which case it would  be on them to examine the land ...)

Comment: If the home was sitting unlevel for many years and you then set it on a level foundation it’s going to take some time to settle back down.

Comment: A home I worked in on a hill had severe settling after an extended draught. A foundation repair company installed over 30 piers and jacked the home back into level posture. Later the walls started cracking and gaps formed. The foundation specialist returned and found that the water table had returned to ore draught levels and pushed the home up off of the piers. They re did the leveling and tied the home down to all piers

Comment: thanks to you both! my sense is it's resettling after being on jacks and being reframed, braced etc. thanks!